# Prove that second iterate of map is a contraction

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, linear-transformations, contraction-operator

Let $T: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ be a linear operator defined as
$$ T f(x)= \int_{0}^x  f(t)dt, \forall x \in [0,1]$$
Space $C[0,1]$ is equipped with supremum norm.
Prove that $T^2$ is a contraction i.e. prove there is a constant $q\in (0,1] $ such that $ d(T^2f, T^2g)\leq q \cdot d(f,g), \forall f,g \in C[0,1] $. $T^2$ is a linear operator, so I consider $T^2 $.

I tried to write $T^2$ as $T(Tf)(x) = \int_{0}^x (T f)(t) dt = \int_{0}^x  \int_{0}^t  f(s) ds dt $

How should I proceed now? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Show $|(T^2f)(x)| \le \int_0^x \int_0^t 1 ds dt \|f\|_\infty$ and evaluate the integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $x\in [0,1]$, you have
$$\left|T^2 f(x)-T^2 g(x)\right|=\left|\int_0^x\int_0^t (f(s)-g(s)) dsdt\right|\leq \int_0^x\int_0^t \|f-g\|_{C[0,1]} ds dt.$$
Therefore,
$$\left|T^2 f(x)-T^2 g(x)\right|\leq \frac{x^2}{2}\|f-g\|_{C[0,1]}\leq \frac{\|f-g\|_{C[0,1]}}{2}.$$
You thus have your contraction with $q=1/2$.